# appendChild not working as expected

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I have this HTML:

```
<ul id="ulref">
    <li>Joe</li>
    <li>Fred</li>
    <li>Steve</li>
</ul>
```

and this JS:

```
ipDOM=document.getElementById("ulref");
x = document.createElement('LI');
y = document.createTextNode("hello");
z = x.appendChild(y);
ipDOM.appendChild(z);
```

So, the "hello" should be a child TextNode of the new LI, I am thinking, but instead both the LI and TextNode both appear as direct children (siblings) of the parent UL instead.  However, if I alter the JS to:

```
ipDOM=document.getElementById("ulref");
x = document.createElement('LI');
y = document.createTextNode("hello");
ipDOM.appendChild(x).appendChild(y);
```

and miss out the z stage, the LI is a child of the UL and the Textnode a child of the LI, as I want.

Why doesn't the first way work as I expected? I am constructing the LI and child TextNode beforehand and then putting that pairing into ipDOM, aren't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) returns the child that was appended to the node.
So after you append the text node to the `li` you append it to the `ul`(removing it from the `li`)

```
ipDOM=document.getElementById("ulref");
x = document.createElement('LI');
y = document.createTextNode("hello");
x.appendChild(y);  // append the text node to the li
ipDOM.appendChild(x); //append the li to the ul
```